# Superscript the outcome of .toFixed()

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, template-strings

In my Vue.js template I have a template string to calculate a total amount. I've used the .toFixed() method to display the decimals. The decimals should be displayed in superscript.

How can I superscript the .toFixed(2) part of my template string below?

```
{{ Number.isInteger(calculation.total) ? (calculation.total + '.-') : 
calculation.total.toFixed(2) }}
```

So the total amount should be displayed as e.g 180.<sup>50</sup> instead of 180.50.

UPDATE: Thank you for letting me know that .sup() is deprecated. How can I achieve the superscript in the template string without the deprecated method? I've rephrased the question.

Comment: `sup()` is deprecated. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sup

Comment: And `sup()` generates `html` which would need `v-html`.

Comment: @pranavjindal999 I would like it to happen within template string which (and I could be wrong) stands separate from vue directives

Comment: not possible in template string. You can write a directive for that.

Comment: @pranavjindal999 How do I target the .toFixed(2) (the part of the template string that needs to be superscripted) with a directive?

Comment: `….toFixed(2).replace(/\.(\d+)/, (_, d) => ".<sup>"+d+"</sup>")`?

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your contribution however it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reusable component which handles all the formatting logic inside it's separate scope.

```js
const Price = {
  template: '<span>{{ int }}.<sup>{{ fraction }}</sup></span>',
  props: {
    value: {
    type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    int() { return Math.floor(this.value); },
    fraction() {
      const i = this.int, v = this.value
      return v === i
        ? '-'
        : Math.round((Math.abs(v) - Math.abs(i)) * 1e2)
    },
  },
}


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Price,
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <Price :value="40.3253" />
</div>
```